# How I can add to variable values in while loop using read line?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I need to do a password input bash script. Bash file must get values from named piped until it receives *.

For example:
Bash gets 1 2 5 6 7 8 ... 5 *  (Each digit comes after press on keypad)

Variable in script must be: Result = 125678...5
And then I have to compare it to my Verif. password

For example(I dont know bash syntax):

```
while read line && input != "*"
do
passWord_input += line


if(passWord_input == verifPassword)
    echo "access granted"
else
    echo "access denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to reinvent the wheel:

```bash
passWord_input=""
while [[ "$passWord_input" != "$verifPassword" ]]; do
    read -s -r -p "Enter Password: " passWord_input
done

echo "valid password entered"
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read

Comment: This code above works not the way I need. It accepts all password digits at once but I need to do it like ATM - one digit by another and when I face the * sign stop the loop and check if inputed password is correct

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a good reason to do this (except perhaps as a homework exercise), but yes, in bash, you can "add variables in a while loop using read". In particular, `man bash` notes of the `+=` operator:

> ```
>    In  the context where an assignment statement is assigning a value to a
>    shell variable or array index, the += operator can be used to append to
>    or  add  to  the variable's previous value.  
>    .
>    .
>    .                                                             When  ap‐
>    plied  to  a  string-valued variable, value is expanded and appended to
>    the variable's value.
> ```

So for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare +i password_input=""
while IFS= read -s -r -n 1 c; do 
  case $c in 
    \*) break
        ;; 
     *) password_input+=$c
        ;; 
  esac
done
```

The `-n 1` arguments allow you to read single characters rather than whole lines. Unsetting the `IFS` variable allows the input to contain characters that would otherwise be consumed by field splitting (which may or may not be a good idea in the case of the default IFS - should passwords be allowed to contain whitespace?).

The explicit `+i` declaration doesn't seem to be required even if the user enters a wholly numeric sequence, but it makes it clear that the intent is to append rather than sum.

FYI the bash syntax for testing string equality is `[[ $str1 == $str2 ]]` .